# MCIWindow with long file path

Tags: c++, mci

I have come across a scenario in my project, where I am creating a MCI window in order to play some videos, wherein it does not play correctly when there is a filepath passed to it which is more than 128 characters long.

I am creating a new MCIWindow like so:

```
m_window = MCIWndCreate( _owner, GetModuleHandle(NULL), WS_CHILD|MCIWNDF_NOERRORDLG|MCIWNDF_NOPLAYBAR|MCIWNDF_NOMENU, shortPath.c_str() );
```

and it will later get played by doing the below:

```
bool VideoMedia::play() 
{
    logStream().I() << "[VideoMedia::play] start\n";

    if ( MCIWndPlay( m_window ) != 0 )
    {
        logStream().E() << "VideoMedia::play " << "\n";
    }
    logStream().I() << "[VideoMedia::play] end\n";
    return true;
}
```

In the case where I am creating the `m_window` using a `shortPath` with length < 128, everything is working perfectly fine with the media showing and playing. However, with a `shortPath` with length > 128, no media is played.  Interestingly, in the `VideoMedia::play()` function above, the logs indicate that the `MCIWndPlay()` call is executing fine, as the error log inside of the if is not seen.

I am wondering if this is just the case that the MCIWnd can not support a long file path, although I have not seen anything in the documentation to suggest this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at documentation [here](http://mmb.mediachance.com/mmbhelp/index.html?mcicommands.htm), it says:

```
NOTE: MCI device has a path-length limit of 128 characters! If your media files are buried inside the nested subfolders and the path is longer than 128 characters, your media won't play.
```

So the only real resolution for this is to ensure that the path does not get any larger than the 128 character restriction it appears.